# How to customize brand list page of my Manufacturer brand logo extension

Tags: magento

I have installed [Manufacturer brand logo module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manufacturer-brand-logo.html).This extension has created a brand list page.How i need to customize that brand list page.

Comment: 1) Enable the template hints from your backend
2) Locate your brand listing (.phtml) file
3) Perform the necessary customizations

Comment: I have enabled the template hints but i can't locate my brand listing page.Because after enable the template hints my entire top menu showing a common path as links.phtml i cant see the menus then how can i get my path for brand page @Vikram

Comment: Check the phtml files of your brand extension in your design folder.

Answer (score 0):

The brand list images are displaying in the default manufacturer.phtml page.

Answer (score 0):

This code add to Product View template Path :-template/catalog/product/view.phtml

This code for  Brand Name:-

getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>

This Code for Manufacture Logo :

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('manufacturer/manufacturer')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('manufacturer/product_manufacturer.phtml')->toHtml();

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The question is two years old. Maybe you can find more current questions to answer. Also, please format any code examples using the `{}` options.